# Add logging to MFC desktop application *Post compile*

Tags: logging, mfc, aop

We have a large legacy application written in C++. I need to track down a bug that only occurs after a long period of time in specific unusual circumstances. We can sometimes get it to fail in the lab.

One avenue I'd like to pursue is some kind of logging injected in after the compilation ala PostSharp for .net but for Microsoft MFC (win32). This is in preference to adding thousands of lines of logging code by hand (but I may end up trying my stretching my python skills to automate a special build it I get nowhere with this.

My internet search skills are failing me (or there is no such thing)

**Notes on wider context:** I am also looking into performance counters and am using crash dumps, but that's for the sate after it's too late, not how to get there. I'm also trying to track down a non-malware [key logger or recording tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805205/video-and-or-key-logger-for-user-activity-before-application-crash)

Comment: Could connecting a debugger be the solution you are searching for?

Comment: connecting a debugger only shows us what is wrong after the fact. It could be useful only if Visual Studio 2005 can add the logging auto-magically for everything that happened on the way to the crash